# How is the 14th amendment relevant to the debt ceiling?

Tags: united-states, debt, fourteenth-amendment

My understanding is:

- The 14th amendment says that any debt the United States has taken on must be honored.
- Previous legislation by Congress prohibits the government from borrowing more than a certain amount of money.

So far so good. I could probably understand the argument that the US government has the constitutional authority & duty to print any money needed to service the current debt. But I don't understand how the 14th amendment could possibly allow an increase of the *debt ceiling* as some are claiming.

How could the obligation to service *existing* debt (by printing money, presumably) possibly confer the authority to take on **new** debt? What is the legal reasoning that would reach this conclusion from that premise?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146200/discussion-on-question-by-user541686-how-is-the-14th-amendment-relevant-to-the-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Congress passes, and the President signs, a legal binding budget for the Federal Government that in broad strokes dictates "we will spend $6.2 Trillion dollars".

They pass this budget, knowing full well that estimated Tax Receipts (how much money the Government takes in) will only be about $4.4 Trillion.

The gap (deficit) of $1.8 Trillion must be borrowed, creating debt.

The problem is that the Budget is legally passed and describes $1.8T to be financed, even though the Debt Ceiling limits that.

The question is which one takes priority?  The Constitutionally mandated Budget, or the Congressionally created Debt Ceiling?

The 14th Amendment seems to indicate that the fulfilling the Budget has a higher priority than the Debt Ceiling construct.

Comment: I think the question at hand is about "the deficit must be borrowed".  OP seems to be thinking that instead of borrowing $1.8T, the government should simply print $1.8T of money and spend it as directed by Congress.

Comment: "The question is which one takes priority? The Constitutionally mandated Budget, or the Congressionally created Debt Ceiling?" What makes the budget constitutionally mandated? It's just a law passed by Congress as well. The Constitution says that they can't default on debt, not that they're obligated to spend everything in the budget.

Comment: @nick012000 While the Constitution does not unambiguously assert that Congress must produce a (yearly) budget, it is implicit that this is a required activity and is typically interpreted as a required part of the job.  However the courts have largely denied themselves any power to force Congress to do such a thing.  Heck, they don't even allow themselves much power to make them do the Census, and that *does* have an unambiguous constitutional mandate. But in this case you have a budget and appropriations already passed, so there's no issue with trying to force one to be done.

Comment: The issue is in exactly how the balance between obligations to debt under the 14th amendment (including how these are even interpreted) and Congress's essentially total control of the purse, including debt payments, is balanced.  There is a school of thought that says the 14th amendment really only says that we cannot unilaterally wipe out our debt, but says nothing about forcing us to pay it.  If so it allows us to basically go "Yep, we have 30 trillion in debt.  We're not paying any of it right now, but it exists; maybe we'll pay it later?" But courts might call that a de facto nullification

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: That seems like a very partial "school of thought". What material difference would the presence or absence of the amendment make in that case?

Comment: @user541686 Potentially very little, but judging by recent trends in conservative jurisprudence and activism, converting amendments or other constitutional clauses, in part or whole, into meaningless nothings (or all powerful everythings, in the case of "independent state legislature" theory) so they cease to conceivably interfere with conservative objectives and control is the goal.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: To be honest I think (some of) the ISL theory is easier to justify than this one. Just reading the constitution plainly, it's clearly saying the legislatures have 
the authority to direct the manner of elections - arguments to the contrary are the ones that require extra evidence (like the state constitutions), not arguments in favor of the plain reading. And the plain interpretation isn't moot. On the other hand, anyone reading 14A would have a hard time interpreting it as anything other than a guarantee that the US will honor their debt as agreed, otherwise it would be moot.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy probably a better example for your point would be 2A, where they literally just ignore half the amendment.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is the appropriations bills that are binding legal authorizations to spend and the budget bill is just an internal Congressional rule or guideline, but the meaning is clear enough.

Comment: @user541686 Except the 14th amendment doesn't exist in a vacuum.  The Constitution by default grants total control over the purse and the payments of debts to Congress.  The 14th amendment did not explicitly repeal that, and so standard SCOTUS construction is that both are valid and must be held in balance.  So how do you balance "must honor this debt as agreed" with "Congress can alter and adjust debt payments however it wants"?  Similarly for ISL, standard court interpretations replace "legislature" (e.g. Congress) with "government"; the executive can't end-run the first amendment, etc.

Comment: And the "shall not be questioned" part seems to require the context of what else is going on: the amendment is *explicitly* repudiating and questioning the validity of certain specific debts (namely, rebel/Confederate debts), in which case there's a certain sense in saying the "shall not be questioned" part is simply a clarification/reassurance that those are the *only* debts that are being unilaterally wiped out and ignored by the US with this amendment.  Those get ignored, the rest are left as-is and treated normally.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy there's already precedent in the constitution for very explicit terminology indicating where a clause is only applicable within certain time periods. If they e.g. didn't intend to include future debts, they could've said do. And the constitution doesn't joke around and write "shall" as a means of mere "clarification" (see 1A). The only "sense" in which those readings make sense to me are the sense in which I have something to lose by reading them differently. They go against the literal text.

Answer (score 2):

The federal government doesn't have the authority to print money.  Under the [Federal Reserve Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/12/414), Congress granted that power exclusively to the Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System ("the Fed").

So if the government needs dollar bills to make payments on outstanding bonds, and doesn't have enough from tax receipts or other such income, the only place to get them is from the Fed.  The Fed can in principle print as many as it likes, but it doesn't give them away for free; it will only give them to the government in payment for something of value, and normally that "something" is bonds.  So the government can only "print more money" indirectly, by issuing more bonds and selling them to the Fed: i.e. taking on more debt.

(The government does retain the authority to mint coins, and there is a frequently raised suggestion that the government could "print more money" by [minting a trillion-dollar coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillion-dollar_coin), and selling *that* to the Fed instead of bonds.  I won't go into that here, but suffice it to say there are a lot of potential legal objections.)

Comment: This is nice information, but doesn't really seem to answer the specific legal question I asked. Aside from the $1T coin and getting the Fed to just money out of thin air, the government could (and I'd argue *must*, but whatever) also use existing revenues to prioritize & pay off creditors before any other spending authorized by Congress, right? So in what way would the obligation to honor existing debts confer the authority to take on *more* debt? I still don't see the logic there. It seems they have a ton of ways to service existing debts without taking on more; they just don't like them.

Comment: Moreover, I see another problem with that argument. Even if the other solutions above are all somehow illegal, why is *taking on more debt* any different, given that's also outlawed by Congress? Heck, if the mere existence of this mechanism somehow confers the authority to use it, then why stop there? Why not just collect more taxes than Congress authorized and then justify it with "oops sorry we don't see any other solution! the constitution requires us to pay our debts somehow!"?

Comment: @user541686: The laws passed by Congress require the government to do three things: (1) collect $X in taxes, (2) spend $Y on the programs that Congress created, (3) do not exceed $Z in debt.  If the government does all three of those, they will be unable to make payments on existing obligations, which the 14th Amendment says they must do.  So the argument is that the combination of 1,2,3 is unconstitutional, and the government is not required to obey all of them.  Violating (3) is much less disruptive than the other two alternatives so it's the choice that the government will prefer.